# Why does my Instagram Wordpress embed only show a photo when logged in?

Tags: wordpress, instagram

When embedding an Instagram photo in a Wordpress post, I'm getting most of the frame displayed but a message "view this post on Instagram" instead of the photo (on iOS only). The frame size is also expanding outside the screen width.

When I log in to Instagram on the browser website, the photo is there and size as expected. This is only happening on iOS (iPhone XS Max). Desktop and iPad both work as expected whether I'm logged in or not.

https://trentsizemore.com/learn/tips-for-marketing-your-photography-on-social-media/

I have tried the wordpress shortcode, pasting the instagram link on a paragraph line, and using the Instagram supplied embed code.